# How do I make canned tomato sauce delicious for pouring on top of steamed vegetables?

Tags: tomatoes

I usually steam mixed vegetables and top it with the following tomato sauce concoction:

- canned diced tomato (salt free)
- cayenne chili powder
- habanero chili powder
- dill weed
- stevia

There’s no cooking of the tomato sauce. It’s kinda of boring over time and I was wondering if there was a way you could recommend for me to spruce up my tomato sauce in a tastier, but healthy way.

Comment: Hi, sadly this type of question isn't a good fit for our site. When people start generating random ideas for adding things, none of them is the objectively correct one, any will work. You can search elsewhere, or just get creative and add anything, then see if you like it.

Answer (score 1):

So, let me get this correct. The tomato product is *right out of the can?*

OK most people notice a distinct metallic taste when consuming (especially acidic) things directly out of a can. It is often less noticeable with sweet things, but I find that I simply can't stomach tomatoes directly out of a can.

Fortunately there is an easy fix, **heat.**

Simmer the diced tomato with your spices (and perhaps a little S&P) for 30 minutes or so and that may give the spices time to meld and reduce the metallic taste.

You could even try some fresh basil as that goes *wonderfully* well with tomato sauce.